# magento Plugin is not working on CollectRates method shipping method class

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, plugin, magento2.1.6

### Target:

Using **plugin before method**, want to changes some behavior of method `collectRates(RateRequest $request)` of  `Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping`

### Issue:

**Getting 500 Internal Server Error**  for parameters of  `beforeCollectRates()`.

***Error message:*** `Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object`

> {"message":"Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array,
>   object given in
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php
>   on line 146","trace":"#0 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'array_values()
>   ...', '/var/www/html/e...', 146, Array)\n#1
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146):
>   array_values(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))\n#2
>   /var/www/html/extension/var/generation/Magento/OfflineShipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping\Interceptor->___callPlugins('collectRates',
>   Array, Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(293):
>   Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping\Interceptor->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))\n#4
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php(209):
>   Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectCarrierRates('freeshipping',
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))\n#5
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(995):
>   Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectRates(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest))\n#6
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(936):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->requestShippingRates()\n#7
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php(161):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->collectShippingRates()\n#8
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php(265):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Shipping->collect(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAssignment),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total))\n#9
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(273):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->collectAddressTotals(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#10
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(213):
>   Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->getShippingMethods(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote),
>   Array)\n#11 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->estimateByExtendedAddress('8',
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#12
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#13
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#14
>   /var/www/html/extension/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#15
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#16
>   /var/www/html/extension/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#17
>   /var/www/html/extension/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))\n#18
>   {main}"}

### Code:

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\CoreRewrite\Plugin;

class FreeShippingPlugin
{
    public function beforeCollectRates(
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $subject ,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request)
    {

        return $request;

    }

}
```

### Question:

***Why i getting issue at parameters of beforeCollectRates()?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
return [$request];
```

The Interceptor is looking for an array as return value from the before method:

```
            $beforeResult = $pluginInstance->$pluginMethod($this, ...array_values($arguments));
            if ($beforeResult) {
                $arguments = $beforeResult;
            }

            [..snip..]

            $result = parent::$method(...array_values($arguments));
```

see [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php#L123).

Comment: Thanks Kristof at Fooman, The   error  been been  vanish.But when i have return `return [false]; ` then shipping method does not disabled

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @[Kristof at Fooman](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/9/kristof-at-fooman) answer,

When you set to return `false` to in your `before` plugin , `Magento` itself call the original method thats why your `return false` seems not working. In that case you can use `after` plugin to change the `return` value. As per I know `before` plugin change only the arguments of the method not the return value.